# Pass 2 Functions Through One OnChange Event - With HREF on both Functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have asked something similar in the past but was able to resolve it by separating the functions by events. I need to be able to pass 2 href events in one Onchange Event because it is a dropdown, OR I need to be able to tie the second function into another Event.

This works only when an alert() is inserted. Once I take the alert() out it does not work. I've tried to supress the alert while still keeping it in the code and it works fine. I do not want the alert but I want the results.

HTML Here:

```
<select id="PartList" class="form-control form-control-lg ml-0" onChange="SelectMain();">
```

JavaScript Here

```
function sList() {
  var pl = document.getElementById("PartList");
  var value = pl.options[pl.selectedIndex].value;
  var text = pl.options[pl.selectedIndex].text;
  str = 'URL1 HERE='+ "'" + text + "'" ;
  //alert(value);
  //alert(text);
  window.location.href = str;
}
function SelectValue() {
  var pv = document.getElementById("PartList");
  var value = pv.options[pv.selectedIndex].value;
  str = 'URL2 HERE' + value ;
  alert(value);
  window.location.href = str;
}
function SelectMain() {
  sList();
  SelectValue();
}
function alert(message) { 
    console.info(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, for those that come to this question. The problem wasn't with the JavaScript it was because the device I was sending the commands to couldn't handle the commands that fast. I have incorporated the resolved code with troubleshooting techniques.

```
function sList() {
  var pl = document.getElementById("PartList");
  var value = pl.options[pl.selectedIndex].value;
  var text = pl.options[pl.selectedIndex].text;
  str = 'URL1='+ "'" + text + "'" ;
  //str1 = 'http://google.com';
  //alert(value);
  //alert(text);
  window.location.href = str;
  //window.open(str1);
}
function SelectValue() {
  setTimeout(function(){
  var pv = document.getElementById("PartList");
  var value = pv.options[pv.selectedIndex].value;
  str = 'URL2=' + value ;
  //str1 = 'http://aol.com';
  //alert(value);
  window.location.href = str;
  //window.open(str1);
},1000);
}
```